# A shorter way to use make_shared?

Tags: c++11

I am about to familiarize myself to C++11 features at the moment. One thing I have liked spontaneously are smart pointers, especially `shared_ptr`. However it does not seem to allow assigning an ordinary pointer to a shared_ptr, ie. for example

```
typedef shared_ptr<string> StringPtr
...
StringPtr x;
...
x = new string("bla");
```

fails, at least in VC2010, and I can understand this of course when looking at the interface of in `shared_ptr::operator=` which is missing an overload for an ordinary pointer of the template argument type. Now I can just create a `shared_ptr` from an ordinary pointer by using the `shared_ptr` constructor explicitly, i.e.

```
x = StringPtr(new string("bla"));
```

but in my opinion this is redundant and counter-intuitive. I think I have expressed my programming intent as much as possible when assigning an ordinary pointer to a smart pointer. Any additional syntax deteriorates readability without gaining much clarity. Of course it is up to me not to assign an already "owned" ordinary pointer to a smart pointer, but so what...

While trying to restore readability I stumbled upon `make_shared<>`. But then again the line

```
x = make_shared<string>("bla");
```

isn't much more readable and compact than the explicit construction of a smart pointer above. Of course performance may be a little bit better, but that's not what I am after. So my intention was to instantiate and alias the function template make_shared like I did for the shared_ptr. But obviously

```
typedef make_shared<string> NewString
```

is not valid at all. So my question is: how can I get closest to writing something like

```
x = NewString("bla");
```

?

Comment: In my oppinion, `std::make_shared<...>(...)` is not only readable, it also explicitly tells what you're doing.

Comment: I've edited the title of your question to avoid confusion because "specialization" has a specific definition in C++ that doesn't apply to your situation.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: basically you're right. It's a matter of taste. But I don't like underscores and I don't like template brackets (but I do like templates of course !). I am reinforced in my dislike any time I am trying to figure out what this neverending intellisense line with 40 parentheses and 20 template brackets is trying to tell my underperforming brain...

Comment: @user2118609: You're probably using an older version of the C++11 compiler that doesn't support [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_Templates), which is required for `make_shared` to accept any arbitrary number of constructor arguments. Older library versions work around this by providing a bunch of overloads that emulate multiple arguments. I can assure you it is much cleaner in newer versions.

Comment: @In silico: I am confused... what multiple number of template arguments are you referring to ? make_shared<string> only got one, as well as the functional argument "bla" is only singular. Actually I am trying to define an alias to a template function or something.

Comment: @user2118609: `make_shared` is not a language keyword, it's actually a function that is defined somewhere in the standard library. (i.e. You could write your own `make_shared`-like function in your own source code). `make_shared` is designed to work with any type, not just `string`s, and types can have any number of constructor arguments of any type. Variadic templates allow `make_shared` to accept any number of constructor arguments of arbitrary types.

Comment: Have a `shared_ptr::reset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work:

```
typedef make_shared<string> NewString
```

is because `make_shared` is not a type, it's a *function*. So if you really wanted to "rename" this, make a wrapper function for it.

```
typedef shared_ptr<string> StringPtr

StringPtr NewString(const char* str)
{
    return make_shared<string>(str);
}

int main()
{
    StringPtr x = NewString("bla"); // works
}
```

However, note that `make_shared` is essentially "standard vocabulary" in C++ by now, so anytime someone runs into `make_shared`, they (should) immediately know what it does. Whereas `NewString`, while the name hints to its function, is still relatively unknown compared to `make_shared` and would have to look at the source or some kind of documentation at first.

---

Side note: `shared_ptr`s do not allow assignment of a raw pointer because that's unsafe.

The way `shared_ptr` works is that it allocates an additional control data structure that holds the reference count (among other things such as deleters). *This control data structure is held separate from the object itself*. Given just an arbitrary a raw pointer, it is not possible to determine if there's already a `shared_ptr` control data structure associated with it. So allowing raw pointer assignment makes it possible for an object to have two or more control data structures associated with it, each with different reference count.

Comment: Thanks very much, In silico. Now I actually feel a little stupid because the wrapper function is so obvious. :-) Maybe I missed this because I have been programming in c# too much, where global functions are not allowed. As to the question of safety: this might be what the designers of shared_ptr had in mind, but nothing keeps me from writing something like shared_ptr<string>(another_shared_ptr.get()), so safety becomes purely imaginary in my opinion... any abuse that can be done, will be done some time.

Comment: @user2118609: True, it's not going to stop a determined idiot. But it does make it harder to use `shared_ptr`s incorrectly, which is always a good thing.